# Chrome Web App: Cannot execute function in game loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I'm a beginner at Chrome Web Apps, and am trying to package a JavaScript/HTML5 clone of Bump'n'Jump as a Packaged App. I am running into a wall with Chrome's security policy:

```
function pump() {
    while (1) {

        game_loop();
        var now = timeGetTime();
        var time_diff = next_time - now;
        next_time += (1000 / 60);

        if (time_diff>0) {
            // we have time left
            setTimeout("pump()", time_diff);
            break;
        }
        // debug("frametime exceeded: " + (-time_diff));
    }
}
```

It refuses to run `setTimeout("pump()", time_diff);`, saying

```
Refused to evaluate script because it violates the following Content Security Policy      directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

The error is not with the code, as it works outside of Chrome in a browser, Chrome's security doesn't seem to like it. Can anyone tell me why it doesn't want to run `pump()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if this will help but try the following: replace the `setTimeout` string parameter:

```
function pump() {
    while (1) {

        game_loop();
        var now = timeGetTime();
        var time_diff = next_time - now;
        next_time += (1000 / 60);

        if (time_diff>0) {
            // we have time left
            setTimeout(pump, time_diff);
            break;
        }
        // debug("frametime exceeded: " + (-time_diff));
    }
}
```

Using string for the execution parameter in `setTimeout` or `setInterval` is the equivalent of an `eval` and is considered bad practice.